# QGIS: habitat suitability/combining raster layers

Tags: qgis, raster, overlay

I have created a number of raster layers for different environmental factors (slope, roads, rivers, forest cover) and want to combine them to find areas where the 'ideal' aspects all overlap. For example, where the slope is not too steep, rivers are within 3km, etc.

I have already added buffers to the roads and streams, as well as reclassified the slope and vegetation layers to have categories. All layers are rasters.

Comment: It would be easier to convert your rasters to vector then use an overlay operation (Union). To make the process easier classify your rasters to suitable/unsuitable before converting to vector then from the overlaid vector select for each criterion only the suitable value.. then I would suggest filtering by size, for example removing areas that are less than 10 ha, even if the multivariate indicates suitability a habitat must be big enough for foraging.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please edit your question to include a focused question.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's a great idea, I was too focussed on changing it to raster for no reason.